# CSS Snippet - when button is clicked opens first element with the other

Tags: html, css

Consider the following snippet.

```css
.text-desc,
[class*="reaction-"],
.field-reactions,
.field-reactions:checked:focus ~ .text-desc {
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.field-reactions:focus ~ .text-desc,
.box:hover [class*="reaction-"],
.field-reactions:checked ~ [class*="reaction-"] {
  clip: auto;
  overflow: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

[class*="reaction-"] {
  border: none;
  background-image: url(http://www.stardating.in/reactions2.png);
  background-color: transparent;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 35px;
  top: -28;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;
  transform: scale(0.1);
  transition: all 0.3s;
  outline: none;
  will-change: transform;
  opacity: 0;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}

.overlays {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.field-reactions:focus ~ .label-reactions {
  border-color: rgba(88, 144, 255, 0.3);
}
.field-reactions:checked:focus ~ .label-reactions {
  border-color: transparent;
}

.label-reactions {
  border: 2px dotted transparent;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.label-reactions img {
  width: auto;
  height: 20px;
}
.label-reactions span {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}
.toolbox {
  background: #fff;
  height: 35px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  width: 130px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: -30px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.15s;
}

.legend-reaction {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 6px;
  transition: opacity 50ms ease;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: -22px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.box:hover [class*="reaction-"] {
  transform: scale(0.8) translateY(-40px);
}
.box:hover [class*="reaction-"]:hover,
.box:hover [class*="reaction-"]:focus {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transform: scale(1) translateY(-35px);
}
.box:hover [class*="reaction-"]:hover .legend-reaction,
.box:hover [class*="reaction-"]:focus .legend-reaction {
  opacity: 1;
}
.box:hover .toolbox {
  opacity: 1;
}
.box:hover .toolbox {
  visibility: visible;
}
.box:hover .reaction-love {
  transition-delay: 0.06s;
}
.box:hover .reaction-haha {
  transition-delay: 0.09s;
}
.box:hover .reaction-wow {
  transition-delay: 0.12s;
}
.box:hover .reaction-sad {
  transition-delay: 0.15s;
}
.box:hover .reaction-angry {
  transition-delay: 0.18s;
}

.field-reactions:checked ~ [class*="reaction-"] {
  transform: scale(0.8) translateY(-40px);
}
.field-reactions:checked ~ [class*="reaction-"]:hover,
.field-reactions:checked ~ [class*="reaction-"]:focus {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transform: scale(1) translateY(-35px);
}
.field-reactions:checked ~ [class*="reaction-"]:hover .legend-reaction,
.field-reactions:checked ~ [class*="reaction-"]:focus .legend-reaction {
  opacity: 1;
}
.field-reactions:checked ~ .toolbox {
  opacity: 1;
}
.field-reactions:checked ~ .toolbox,
.field-reactions:checked ~ .overlays {
  visibility: visible;
}
.field-reactions:checked ~ .reaction-love {
  transition-delay: 0.03s;
}
.field-reactions:checked ~ .reaction-haha {
  transition-delay: 0.09s;
}
.field-reactions:checked ~ .reaction-wow {
  transition-delay: 0.12s;
}
.field-reactions:checked ~ .reaction-sad {
  transition-delay: 0.15s;
}
.field-reactions:checked ~ .reaction-angry {
  transition-delay: 0.18s;
}

.reaction-like {
  left: 5px;
  background-position: 0px -148px;
}

.reaction-love {
  background-position: -35px 0px;
  left: 45px;
}

.reaction-haha {
  background-position: -70px 0px;
  left: 87px;
}

.reaction-wow {
  background-position: -144px 0;
  left: 150px;
}

.reaction-sad {
  background-position: -192px 0;
  left: 200px;
}

.reaction-angry {
  background-position: -240px 0;
  left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<br><br>
<div class="box">
  <input type="checkbox" id="like" class="field-reactions">
  <label for="like" class="label-reactions"><img src="http://www.stardating.in/star.png"> <span>Like</span></label>
  <div class="toolbox"></div>
  <label class="overlays" for="like"></label>
  <button class="reaction-like"><span class="legend-reaction">Like</span></button>
  <button class="reaction-love"><span class="legend-reaction">Love</span></button>
  <button class="reaction-haha"><span class="legend-reaction">Hot</span></button>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <input type="checkbox" id="like" class="field-reactions">
  <label for="like" class="label-reactions"><img src="http://www.stardating.in/star.png"> <span>Like</span></label>
  <div class="toolbox"></div>
  <label class="overlays" for="like"></label>
  <button class="reaction-like"><span class="legend-reaction">Like</span></button>
  <button class="reaction-love"><span class="legend-reaction">Love</span></button>
  <button class="reaction-haha"><span class="legend-reaction">Hot</span></button>
</div>


<div class="box">
  <input type="checkbox" id="like" class="field-reactions">
  <label for="like" class="label-reactions"><img src="http://www.stardating.in/star.png"> <span>Like</span></label>
  <div class="toolbox"></div>
  <label class="overlays" for="like"></label>
  <button class="reaction-like"><span class="legend-reaction">Like</span></button>
  <button class="reaction-love"><span class="legend-reaction">Love</span></button>
  <button class="reaction-haha"><span class="legend-reaction">Hot</span></button>
</div>


<div class="box">
  <input type="checkbox" id="like" class="field-reactions">
  <label for="like" class="label-reactions"><img src="http://www.stardating.in/star.png"> <span>Like</span></label>
  <div class="toolbox"></div>
  <label class="overlays" for="like"></label>
  <button class="reaction-like"><span class="legend-reaction">Like</span></button>
  <button class="reaction-love"><span class="legend-reaction">Love</span></button>
  <button class="reaction-haha"><span class="legend-reaction">Hot</span></button>
</div>


<div class="box">
  <input type="checkbox" id="like" class="field-reactions">
  <label for="like" class="label-reactions"><img src="http://www.stardating.in/star.png"> <span>Like</span></label>
  <div class="toolbox"></div>
  <label class="overlays" for="like"></label>
  <button class="reaction-like"><span class="legend-reaction">Like</span></button>
  <button class="reaction-love"><span class="legend-reaction">Love</span></button>
  <button class="reaction-haha"><span class="legend-reaction">Hot</span></button>
</div>


<div class="box">
  <input type="checkbox" id="like" class="field-reactions">
  <label for="like" class="label-reactions"><img src="http://www.stardating.in/star.png"> <span>Like</span></label>
  <div class="toolbox"></div>
  <label class="overlays" for="like"></label>
  <button class="reaction-like"><span class="legend-reaction">Like</span></button>
  <button class="reaction-love"><span class="legend-reaction">Love</span></button>
  <button class="reaction-haha"><span class="legend-reaction">Hot</span></button>
</div>
```

Hover on the buttons one by one and you can see how beautifully and smoothly the snippet is working. Now click on any element except the first one. You will see that on click it opens up the reaction toolbox for the very first element, every time. I don't know why is it happening. It works fine on hover but not on click. Any solution would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Element not working properly on multiple items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58673969/css-element-not-working-properly-on-multiple-items)

Comment: @Bauke that had a separate problem now solved. This is a different problem.